# nodejs fs createWriteStream save multiple files with same name

Tags: node.js, file-upload, filestream, fs

How to store multiple files with same name and extension using fs.

```
fs.createWriteStream(`${dir}${file.filename}`)
```

What I want is:

upload image.jpg -> uploaded image.jpg

upload image.jpg -> uploaded image-2.jpg

upload image.jpg -> uploaded image-3.jpg

Currently I can not upload new file with same name

Comment: You have to detect if the target name already exists on disk and, if so, generate a unique suffix for the base filename such as `-1`.  It's just code to write this yourself.  As this problem has been solved many times before, there may be some modules that do something like this for you.  Worth looking.